# O que é parameter sniffing?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Já ouvi falar de parameter sniffing. Alguma coisa a ver com SQL Server, stored procedures, e parametros. Mas o que é exatamente?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quando uma *stored procedure* vai ser executada pela primeira vez, o SQL Server compila o procedimento e gera um *plano de ação*, que fica armazenado no *cache*, e é utilizado nas chamadas subsequentes à essa mesma *procedure*.

Isso é feito dessa forma para evitar que o processo de compilar a *procedure* seja repetido a cada chamada, por ser uma tarefa que consome muitos recursos da CPU.

Porém, há um detalhe importante: nesse processo de compilação da *procedure*, o SQL Server busca montar o melhor plano de ação possível. O plano de ação **ótimo**. Na montagem desse melhor plano, o compilador considera o **valor dos parâmetros** - é aí que está o ***parameter sniffing***: é o compilador de *procedures* do SQL Server **espiando o contéudo dos parâmetros enviados para a *procedure*** a fim de elaborar e montar o melhor plano de ação a ser armazenado em *cache* e reutilizado depois.

Isso descreve como o SQL Server opera normalmente.

A questão do ***parameter sniffing*** torna-se importante quando ocorre que o "melhor plano de ação" para uma determinada *procedure* difere consideravelmente de acordo com o valor do parâmetro. Isso tem o potencial de gerar a desagradável situação: na primeira chamada, quando a compilação acontece, pode ser utilizado um parâmetro que gera uma plano de ação que pode ser ótimo para aquele parâmetro. Porém, numa chamada posterior, pode acontecer de que um valor diferente para o parâmetro tenha uma performance terrível usando aquele plano de ação que foi o melhor para o *outro* valor do parâmetro, passado anteriormente.

O desenvolvedor precisa conhecer esse mecanismo do *parameter sniffing* para se precaver da situação mencionada. Ou seja, é um mecanismo que a princípio serve para otimizar a performance, mas que pode vir a resultar no seu oposto, prejudicando a performance.

Fonte: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/

(Na matéria usada como fonte, as soluções para evitar os problemas gerados pelo *parameter sniffing* são abordadas.)